# comparing system date to a log date and display only log entries after system date - pshell

Tags: powershell, date, split

I have log file with a date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,FFF` for example:

```
2018-11-20 15:45:58,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-20 15:45:58,021 [No|SeSt] [2] [Session#-2,Username=2] INFO  is running
2018-11-20 15:45:58,031 [No|SeSt] [3] [Session#-3,Username=3] INFO  is running
```

I need to compare this to the system date and display only logs which are greater than a set system date

I have a `$logDate` already in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,FFF` format but the `$_.[datetime]` is actually a system date with todays date and 00:00:00,000

```
get-content -Path $file -Tail 100 |  where-object {  $_.[datetime] $_.split()[0] -le $logDate}
```

I probably need to extract the date from the log file 1st?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to get the items after "today"? from the future? [*grin*] or do you want to get lines after some specified date? or do you want items from today that are after a certain _time_?

Answer (score 1):

this does what you seem to be describing. however, i can't think of why you are testing for dates in the *future* ... [*grin*]

```
# read in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
2018-11-21 21:21:21,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-19 19:19:19,021 [No|SeSt] [2] [Session#-2,Username=2] INFO  is running
2018-11-20 20:20:20,031 [No|SeSt] [3] [Session#-3,Username=3] INFO  is running
2018-11-22 22:22:22,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-23 23:23:23,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-18 18:18:18,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

# get today at midnite, not "now"
$Today = (Get-Date).Date

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $DateString = $IS_Item.Split(' ')[0].Trim()
    $ParsedDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $Null)

    if ($ParsedDate -gt $Today)
        {
        $IS_Item
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
2018-11-21 21:21:21,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-22 22:22:22,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
2018-11-23 23:23:23,011 [No|SeSt] [1] [Session#-1,Username=1] INFO  is running
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command isn't that bad and much more efficient than @Lee_Dailey's answer,
just the `$_.` in front of `[datetime]` has to be removed (and -le should be -gt),
but uses only the date to compare.

Presuming you want to compare **all** date elements including fractions of seconds:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\20\SO_53398055.ps1
$File = '.\SO_53398055.log'
$dtFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,FFF'
$logDate = [datetime]::ParseExact('2018-11-20 15:45:58,018',$dtFormat,$Null)

Get-Content -Path $file -Tail 100 |
  Where-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact( ($_.split('[')[0]).Trim(), $dtFormat,$Null) -gt $logDate}
```

The Where looks a bit crowded because I use the `[` to split the input line and then need to trim the trailing space.
My choosen `logDate` is between the 1st and 2nd log entry and as your text says `only logs which are greater than a set system date` deviating from your code which compares  less or even I expect this output

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\20\SO_53398055.ps1
2018-11-20 15:45:58,021 [No|SeSt] [2] [Session#-2,Username=2] INFO  is running
2018-11-20 15:45:58,031 [No|SeSt] [3] [Session#-3,Username=3] INFO  is running
```

Comment: yeah -le should be -gt cuz i was steting whats being displayed from the log :) - sorry my bad when copy/paste

Comment: thanks, yeah i am running this to check the log file when the service is starting and fully started. Meaning even the service is "Running" it does not mean its truly started, only log can tell me if service is up or not.